# check if <font> html tag has color and add label | js | jq

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have this HTML:

```
<font color="#ff0000">מתחנת חוף הכרמל</font>
```

I want to check if it has the `color` style and if it does I want to add a `label` to it. This is what I tried to do with no success:

```
if ($("font").css('color') == '#ff0000' ) {
   $("font").attr('role':'heading');
} else {
   console.log('not working');
}
```

Any advice? If it's possible also with pure JS it will be great.

Comment: The return value of `.css('color')` is actually the string `"rgb(255,0,0)"` for that element. Not '#ff0000'. `alert()` is a wonderful tool :) Use classes for styles instead of inline, then detection and styling is much easier

Comment: Also `attr('role':'heading')` is a syntax error. The `:` needs to be a `,`. A much better solution here is to use a class to apply the `color` styling, then use JS to check for the presence of the class on that element. Also note that the `<font>` element is not valid HTML and should not be used. See: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features

Comment: font tag hasn't been used since the 1997 when it was deprecated!  It has now been obsolete since 2014 so whatever your using to learn your html, you need to get an up to date version

Comment: thanks, the font tag is old i know, i'm working on a very old site :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
<font style="color:#ff0000;">מתחנת חוף הכרמל</font>

var col = document.getElementsByTagName('font')[0].style.color;
 if(col=='rgb\(255, 0, 0\)') {
   document.getElementsByTagName('font')[0].setAttribute('role','heading');
 } else {
   console.log('do stuff...');
 }
```

check the fiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/r2sb0hjn/

Comment: you cannot get the color if you don't explicitly write it as a style attribute/tag(css)

Comment: the color you got for #ff0000 is rgb(255,0,0) red=full, green=0 and blue=0! Please vote for the answer if it helped you

Comment: oh you mean getElementsByTagName('font')[0]? in this case getElementsByTagName will give you an array of all "font"-tag element and [0] means pick the first element up. it's better to have a class or an id for font-tag (then use getElementByClassName/getElementById)